# Classes no JavaScript em uma aplicação com o Cordova

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

Quando tento declarar uma classe no JavaScript, usando, por exemplo:

```
class musica{ 
    contructor(){ 
      this.variavel = 3;
    } 
    funcao(){
      console.log('essa é a minha variável: '+ this.variavel);
    }
}
```

Na minha aplicação tenho o seguinte erro:

> *Uncaught SyntaxError: unknown message reserved_word*

Não é possível criar classes no JS usando o Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova não suporta ES6, classes, da forma que você fez, só estão disponíveis a partir dele. Entenda que muitas tecnologias ainda são experimentais e não formam implementadas totalmente.

O Ionic com cordova usa classes, mas, na verdade, não é JavaScript e sim TypeScript que, no **build** é "compilado" (recodificado) para JavaScript.

Talvez você encontre alguns artigos por ai que falem que é possível usar ES6 no Cordova, mas, na verdade, estes artigos estão falando do **projeto Babel**:

- http://babeljs.io

Que é um 'compilador' que transforma o seu script like ES6 em "ES5", ou seja, lhe permite usar ES6 antes de estar disponível.